# SharePoint webpart and application page

Tags: web-part, javascript, asp.net, application-pages

I need to make an application page or a webpart that have a javascript code and i tried to add the jquery i a new project to upload it to the SharePoint but the code didn't work 
this is the code that i am tried to run the same Visual Studio project

```
<asp:Content ID="PageHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead"
runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
$('ul#people > li').css('background-color', '#ADD8E6');
});
</script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<div id="myId">
<p>
Paragraph before List</p>
<ul id="people">
<li>Phill</li>
<li>Pip</li>
<li>Les</li>
<li>Denise</li>
<li>Martin</li>
<li>Helen</li>
<li></li>
</ul>
<p>
Paragraph after List</p>
<div>
<p>
Paragraph inside another div</p>
</div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to:

1. Make sure you got jQuery properly loaded. Falak's approach
   absolutely valid, is but one of the most quicker - you need to make
   sure you upload your jQuery library in the _layouts/js folder prior
   to testing. There are other ways to load JQUery, such as using the
   ScriptLink (see here
   http://tommdaly.wordpress.com/2010/12/16/scriptlink-vs-whats-the-difference/)
   or a Custom Actions (see here
   http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2010/03/01/scriptsrc-referencing-javascript-files-with-sharepoint-2010-custom-actions.aspx)
2. Check by code if jQuery is really loaded using either

   ```
   if (jQuery) {  
   // jQuery is loaded  
   } else  { // jQuery is not loaded }
   ```

   //or use this
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') 
   {   // jQuery is not loaded
                   } else {  // jQuery is loaded }

Comment: There are many elegant approaches where you can add controls/scripts to pages without modifying the master page, DelegateControls, ScriptLink etc., but it's up to you to decide which suits your application best.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, let’s make sure if you are loading a copy of the jQuery script in the application page. For e.g.

`<script language="javascript" src="http://yoursite/_layouts/js/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: should i have to upload it in the same application page ??

Comment: deploying the jQuery Script File to Layouts can easily be done via VS2010. In your Right-click your project and add a SharePoint "Layouts" Mapped Folder. Include the jQuery file and you're good to go